# Asymptote: How can I mix two colours

Tags: color, asymptote

In latex, I can mix two colours like `RoyalBlue!25!white`.
In asymptote I want to use the same color. How do I do this?

MWE where I would like to replace the RoyalBlue color of the material by the above one:

```
size(700);
import solids;
import texcolors;
import three;

currentprojection=orthographic (
    camera=(8,4,4),
    up=(0,0,1),
    target=(2,2,2),
    zoom=1.0
);

// save predefined 2D orientation vectors
pair NN=N;
pair SS=S;
pair EE=E;
pair WW=W;

triple Atom1 = (-1.1547, -2., 3.26599);

material m  = material(gray(0.5), black, RoyalBlue, black);

draw(surface(sphere(Atom1,0.5)),m);
```

Comment: `interp(RoyalBlue, white, 0.75)`, where `interp` stands for "interpolate", will give you 75% of the way from `RoyalBlue` to `white`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the binary operator `*` to scale the colors/pens, and the binary operator `+` to add colors/pens together.

Therefore, replacing `RoyalBlue` with `RoyalBlue*0.25 + white*0.75` (25 % RoyalBlue mixed with 75 % white) should yield the output you want.

```
size(700);
import solids;
import texcolors;
import three;

currentprojection=orthographic (
    camera=(8,4,4),
    up=(0,0,1),
    target=(2,2,2),
    zoom=1.0
);

// save predefined 2D orientation vectors
pair NN=N;
pair SS=S;
pair EE=E;
pair WW=W;

triple Atom1 = (-1.1547, -2., 3.26599);

material m  = material(gray(0.5), black, RoyalBlue*0.25 + white*0.75, black);

draw(surface(sphere(Atom1,0.5)),m);
```

This gives the output
[image: Output]

Answer (score 5):

You can combine colors like in the following example.

```
unitsize(3inch);
for (real fred = 0.0; fred <= 1.0; fred += 0.1) {
    for (real fblue = 0.0; fblue <= 1.0; fblue += 0.1) {
        fill(shift(fred,fblue)*scale(0.1)*unitsquare, fred*red+fblue*blue);
    }
}
```

[image]